# Using Facebook graph Api in c# windows application

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to start with graph Api in windows application. I created a facebook app and see some articles about graph Api but unfortunately I did not understand. I want to get data like: Messages, Events, Friends, Wall posts,...  from facebook.

What is the first step for this?

What is **access token** and if it is a constant string or changes for every request?

Do you have a very basic sample for this?

Any help will be so appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at it ... https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk

Comment: I would like to ask you first read something from https://developer.facebook.com  Then if you have any doubts come here ....

Comment: Thanks dear xpertgun. Can you please answer my second question(Access token)? and I read your link before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access token will expire in 2 to 3 hours and we can extend it for 60 days. For that we need to create an application in facebook. And based on this access token will be vary and not constant.

** What is Access Token **

An access token is a random string that gives an app temporary and secure access to Facebook APIs. And access token can be created on behalf of a person, a Facebook Page or an app. The token is generated in the last step of the login flow. Facebook SDKs handle the generation and storage of tokens automatically. Apps using other methods will need to follow the login flow to create tokens.

The token stores information about permissions that have been granted as well as information about when the token will expire and which app generated it. To maintain information security, almost all API calls at Facebook need to have an access token passed in the parameters of the request.

Go through this link for [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/)